# ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:38:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HttpClientModule'

Tags: angular

I am using Angular-8 for a particular project.

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { LoginModule } from './login/login.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ErrorsModule } from './errors/errors.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PagesModule } from './pages/pages.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SidebarComponent } from './shared/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducers, metaReducers } from './store/reducers';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { AppEffects } from './store/effects/app.effects';
import { JwtInterceptor } from './core/interceptors/jwt.interceptor';
import { ErrorInterceptor } from './core/interceptors/error.interceptor';
import { CacheInterceptor } from './core/interceptors/cache.interceptor';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
  RouterModule,
  BrowserModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  LoginModule,
  CoreModule,
  SharedModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  ErrorsModule,
  PagesModule,
  FormsModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
    metaReducers,
    runtimeChecks: {
      strictStateImmutability: true,
      strictActionImmutability: true
    }
  }),
  !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : [],
  EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects]),
  StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
    maxAge: 25,
    logOnly: environment.production
  }),
  ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
    enabled: environment.production
  })
],
```

When I did ng serve, I got this error:

> ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:38:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HttpClientModule'.

This is the Line 38:

> HttpClientModule,

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

HttpClient got introduced in Angular 4.3.0 version. Also you have to make sure you have imported & injected HttpClientModule in your main AppModule's imports metadata.

```js
 // Import HttpClientModule from @angular/common/http in AppModule
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';


//in place where you wanted to use `HttpClient`
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```